# Present NextGen Gallery album through link

Tags: plugin-nextgen-gallery

I'm using the NextGen Gallery and would simply like to present one of my albums in a popover gallery through an anchor link.

Currently I'm only aware of being able to use the `ngg` short code to insert an album into my page. This is not what I want. I don't want the images to show on the page. I would like to have a link and upon clicking the link, my NextGen album is presented in a popover gallery.

I don't care which popover gallery is used. Lightbox, Fancybox, etc. any will do.

Is there a short code I can use with `ngg` or maybe an additional plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With NextGEN Pro you use the Pro Lightbox. Then insert an album with it set to open galleries in the Pro Lightbox.